# Binding new types in a component so that child components can inject them

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Say I have many instances of a component, and it consists of child components, or maybe even a hierarchy of components beneath it.  The top-level component may have data that the child components are interested in.  There are a couple ways I've tried to handle this:

- Injecting the parent component into the child components.
- Pass data through mapped attributes.

The first solution introduces a lot of coupling, and the second solution is verbose and messy.  What I'd like to do is create a simple model class that the parent component would instantiate and bind so that child components could inject it, without affecting any injector outside the hierarchy.  I tried creating a child injector and binding the model there, but it didn't work (the children don't use the child injector, which makes sense).

I'm pretty certain angular does something like this for injecting elements into components, but I couldn't figure out how after a cursory search.  So, is this possible?  How would I do it?

Comment: I didn't work with Angular for a while and my knowledge became stale, but I would expect when you bind the instance in the parent component that it should be injectable in the children. Have you tried this? Could you add some example code to your question?

Comment: The injector can be injected into to parent component, but you cannot bind types to an injector -- they are bound to a module.  The injector exposes a method called `createChild` that you pass a module to, but this doesn't mean that the child components will use the child injector (I tried, but was right in assuming it wouldn't work).

Comment: A while back I read about work to allow to define modules inside a component. Maybe this can do what you need. I found only https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/pull/779 AFAIR there was a longer discussion about it.

Comment: Found it: https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/652 I guess it will still not allow to bind types/values at runtime.

Comment: That worked!  Can you post as answer so I can mark it?  Thanks!

Comment: That's great to know! I added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a module in a directive or component.

```dart
 * Example:
 *
 *     @NgDirective(selector: '[foo]', module: FooDirective.initModule)
 *     FooDirective {
 *       static initModule() => new Module()..type(SomeTypeA);
 *     }
 *
```

see:

- https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/pull/779
- https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/652